# How to convert enrollment code to course id?

Tags: rest, google-classroom

Is there a way to get a course identifier (`id`, course object itself .etc) from an enrollment code with an HTTP request?

I don't see any way to do so in the [classroom REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/).

Similar to scripting a join screen, how do I convert an enrollment code obtained from a GoogleTeacher to a classroom `id` which I can then use with an API call like `GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/id` (`Classroom.Courses.get()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be no direct way to query `courses` by the `enrollmentCode` - but one can `list` all courses to get their `courseId`s and then use `get` by `courseId`, in order to compare the `enrollmentCode` of that `course` and return the `room`, when the `enrollmentCode` matches.

see the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses).

Comment: I understand that. So does it mean if I want to join class by API, I must have both course `id` and `enrollmentCode` ?

Comment: @WilliamLi the `enrollmentCode` is only required when joining as a student:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create

Comment: I will be most likely requesting as a student in my application, but is it impossible to join a class without an `id`?

Comment: I suppose the question is answered... I am starting a new question